# Is it possible to use tcolorbox in XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, double-sided, tcolorbox

This is a trivial color box, which provided by tcolorbox package:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

In XeLaTeX, it works good in even pages, but cause overfull hbox in odd pages:
[image: Incorrect color box in XeLaTeX]

The **twoside** class option has been activated and margin parameters are

```
\oddsidemargin=-10.4mm  
\evensidemargin=-20.4mm 
\topmargin=-35mm        
\textwidth=190mm        
\textheight=275mm
```

It appears OK in LaTeX. Is it possible to use correctly in XeLaTeX, too?

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bidi}    

\oddsidemargin=-10.4mm  
\evensidemargin=-20.4mm 
\topmargin=-35mm        
\textwidth=190mm        
\textheight=275mm       

\begin{document}
Text test
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage
Text test
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: While creating the MWE, I've detected that the reason is **bidi** package. If to disable \usepackage{bidi} row, it becomes OK. Personally I don't need **bidi** package, but if anyone use XeLaTeX, bidi and tcolorbox, question is still opened. Please check MWE in question field.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why `tcolorbox` is indented notwithstanding the fact that it issues `\noindent`; probably some bad interaction with `bidi`. You can solve the problem by redefining the `noparskip` key and setting `\parindent` to zero (which is set to anyway inside a `tcolorbox`).

If you use a non zero parskip, you have to redefine accordingly the `parskip` key.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bidi}    

\tcbset{
  noparskip/.style={before={\par\smallskip\pagebreak[0]\parindent=0pt },
                    after={\par\smallskip}}
}

\begin{document}

Text test

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.\showthe\parindent
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage
Text test

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different workaround (thanks to Marco Daniel for suggesting it) can be to conditionally add `\noindent` to the redefinition of `\pgfpicture` performed by `bidi`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bidi}    

\newif\iftcbnoindent
\tcbset{
  noparskip/.style={before={\par\smallskip\pagebreak[0]\noindent\tcbnoindenttrue},
                    after={\par\smallskip}}
}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\@ifpackageloaded{bidi}
 {\def\pgfpicture{%
   \ifmmode\else
     \LTR
     \iftcbnoindent\tcbnoindentfalse\noindent\fi % <-- addition
     \beginL
   \fi
   \origin@pgfpicture}}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text test

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage
Text test

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest the following `\edef\origparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent}
\tcbset{
  noparskip/.style={before={\par\smallskip\pagebreak[0]\parindent=0pt },
                    after={\par\smallskip}},
 before upper = {\origparindent},
 before lower = {\origparindent},
}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel If I say `\showthe\parindent` inside a `tcolorbox`, I get 0pt, as usual in a `\parbox`. This might be a good addition to the package, but is another question. Since keys are evaluated after `\begin`, there should be no difference in behavior.